# Laravel 5 Eloquent join 2 table got Property [tradeHistories] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel-5, query-builder, eloquent

I have a problem here, and I don't have any idea why it's happened, because I followed the tutorial on youtube precisely.

Here is the problem:

**Account.php**

```
#region Relationship: one to many
public function tradeHistories() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\TradeHistory');
}
#endregion
```

**TradeHistory.php**

```
#region Relationship: one to many (reversed)
public function account() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Account');
}
#endregion
```

**AccountsController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $accounts = Account::all();
    dd($accounts->tradeHistories);
    return view('pages.account.index')
            ->with('active', 'account')
            ->with('accounts', $accounts);
}
```

In returns I got this message

> "Property [tradeHistories] does not exist on this collection instance."

So why I got that message? because I want to show all the trade histories for all account.

Comment: try to give it bracket

Comment: where should I put it? Sorry I just started learning laravel

Comment: if you mean the `tradeHistories()`, I already tried it and I got this **"Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::tradeHistories does not exist."**

Comment: can you please run php artisan cache:clear OR php artisan:optimize ?

Comment: and to add over @rahulsm comment he meant \Account::all() , to prevent an undefined class

Comment: @PedroFaria99 I already run artisan cache:clear and it's success but nothing changes, and for the artisan:optimize it diesnt working, it says **could not open input file: artisan:optimize**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `$accounts` is a collection of accounts, so each separate item in the collection will have access to `tradeHistories`. For example the first item:

```
$accounts = Account::all();
dd($accounts->first()->tradeHistories);
```

or looping all the items each one will have access to it:

```
foreach ( $accounts as $account ) {
    dd($account->tradeHistories);
}
```

I would recommend eager loading the `tradeHistories` so each account item does not make an extra query: `$accounts = Account::with('tradeHistories')->get();`.

Comment: After I put this `$accounts = Account::with('tradeHistories')->get();` why does it giving me an error like this **Unknown column 'trade_histories.account_account_number'** because the field column is `account_number` not `account_account_number`

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya you have to modify the relation in the model, because your table foreign key columns do not match the Eloquent convention. Try this `return $this->hasMany('App\TradeHistory', 'account_number');` or modify it according to your table column.

Comment: why did I got this **"Property [phptradeHistories] does not exist on this collection instance."**? after I add the account number field

Comment: I just try to `dd` the raw data of $accounts, why I see this `#relations: []`? because I think I should see some relation right?

Comment: @KhrisnaGunanasurya `tradeHistories()` relates to a single **account**; `$accounts` is a **collection** of many accounts, so you need a **single** account model to access the relation to tradeHistories.

Comment: I see, now it's working but now it returns `#relations: ["clients" => null]`, but it's getting better now, thanks to you

Comment: Ah nvm, I got it now, Thanks!